# WPF – Wrong scrolling in a reverse ordered (bottom to top) ListBox

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, scrollbar

I have the following code to reverse a `ListBox` (items are placed form bottom to top):

```
<ListBox HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch">          
    <ListBox.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <VirtualizingStackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Orientation="Vertical">
                <VirtualizingStackPanel.LayoutTransform>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                </VirtualizingStackPanel.LayoutTransform>
            </VirtualizingStackPanel>
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ListBoxItem">
            <Setter Property="LayoutTransform">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ScaleTransform ScaleX="1" ScaleY="-1" />
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.ItemContainerStyle>
</ListBox>
```

If you add some items, you will see that the scrollbar is wrong (original instead inverse). What can I do to transform the scrollbar like done with the content? BTW, If you set  `ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False"` in the ListBox the scrolling is fine. But then Virtualization is lost.

Comment: Why not reverse the order of the list before setting it to the `ListBox.Items`? Or use a converter to reverse the `ListBox.ItemsSource` if you are using bindings?

Comment: Because I just want to display the reverse order. Furthermore the items should be displayed from bottom to top (the item stack should also aligned bottom) and not, like usual, from top to bottom.